# How can I run this code once so that my generated post title doesn't keep changing on publish/update?

Tags: custom-post-types, title, filters

I have a custom post type called `transaction`, and on the post type's edit/publish screen I have removed the post title field. The post title is now being generated by the function below, which labels each post `Transaction` followed by a unique string, thanks to the `uniqid` PHP function.

I'm running this function on the `title_save_pre` filter but every time I update the post, a new unique number being generated for the title.

How can I modify the code below so that the unique number for the title is only generated once?

```
function transaction_title( $title ) {

  $screen = get_current_screen();
  $transaction_number = uniqid(); // unique number

  if ( 'transaction' == $screen->post_type ) {
     return 'Transaction '. $transaction_number;
  } else {
    return $title; // else return the normal title
  }
}
add_filter( 'title_save_pre', 'transaction_title');
```

My initial thoughts are to set a post meta flag [like this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47566/post-publish-only-hook) but I'm having trouble combining it with my function. It seems that it only updates the post meta when I use the `transition_post_status` action and doesn't with my `title_save_pre` filter (which I need to change the title).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function transaction_title( $title )
{


    if ( 'transaction' == get_current_screen()->post_type && '' == $title )
    {
        return 'Transaction '.uniqid();
    }
    // else return the normal title
    else 
    {
        return $title;
    }
}
add_filter( 'title_save_pre', 'transaction_title' );
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work, but thanks for the push in the right direction. Got it working now. Just needed to do a simple check on the title.

Comment: In this case, just edit my answer and make it correct - at least this answers should help later users too :)

Comment: Oops good point, I'll update yours now :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [wp_insert_post_data()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) ? This [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6406/dynamically-set-wordpress-post-title-to-the-category-name) may also help you.